# I have trained yolov5 for fire and smoke detection

Tags: yolov5

[The error message you're encountering suggests a mismatch between the number of channels in the input tensor and the number of channels expected by a convolutional layer in your neural network model. Let's break down the error message and potential causes:

RuntimeError: This indicates that an error occurred during runtime, while the program was executing.

Given groups=1, weight of size [32, 3, 6, 6]: This part of the message refers to the weight tensor of a convolutional layer in your model. The size [32, 3, 6, 6] suggests that this layer has 32 filters, each with a size of 3x6x6.

expected input[1, 640, 640, 3] to have 3 channels, but got 640 channels instead: This part of the message points to the input tensor you provided to the model. The expected input shape is [1, 640, 640, 3], which means a batch size of 1, image dimensions of 640x640 pixels, and 3 channels (e.g., RGB channels). However, the error indicates that the input actually has 640 channels.

The error occurs because there's a mismatch in the number of channels between the input tensor and the convolutional layer's weight tensor. The convolutional layer expects an input with 3 channels, but it received an input with 640 channels.

To fix this issue, you should examine the code where you define or process the input data, as well as the architecture of your neural network model. Make sure that the input tensor you're passing to the model has the correct number of channels (3 in this case) and that the layers in your model are configured appropriately to handle the input tensor's shape.

Here's a checklist of things to consider:

Check the code where you load or preprocess your input data. Make sure the images have 3 channels (e.g., RGB images) and are of the expected dimensions.

Examine the architecture of your neural network model, specifically the layers that are connected to the layer mentioned in the error message. Ensure that the number of input channels matches the expected number of channels for those layers.

If you're using a pre-trained model or weights, verify that you're using the correct weights for the specific model architecture you're using.

If you're building a custom model, review the layers' configurations, especially the number of input and output channels for each convolutional layer.

By carefully reviewing these aspects of your code and model architecture, you should be able to identify and fix the source of the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejGZ5.png)